# Set NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW on particular products

Tags: magento-1, products, seo, index

My magento store has the following to allow google/search engines to crawl the entire site.

```
<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" />
```

I am now in need for some particular products to have:

```
<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW" />
```

so that google doesn't crawl/index them. Is this possible? Products would be random (i.e not all from one category) so I need to be able to do this on a product by product basis if needed.

I know i could do it on a url basis like:

```
<?php
$currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
if ($currentUrl == 'xxxxxxx')
{
    <meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW" />
}
else
{
    <meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" />
}
?>
```

but there could end up over time to be hundreds/thousands of these.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Magento admin, when editing a product go to the tab `design` and add the following to `custom layout`:

```
<reference name="head">
      <action method="setRobots"><meta>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</meta></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: @paj true but products are random so this is the only clean option.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<value>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</value>` instead of `<meta>NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW</meta>`?

Answer (score 18):

you can observe the event `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` like this:

```
public function setRobots($observer) 
{
     $controller = $observer->getAction();
     $fullActionName = $controller->getFullActionName();
     if ($fullActionName == 'catalog_product_view') { //if on product page
          $product = Mage::registry('product'); //access the current product if needed
          if (your condition here) { //condition to set the robots to noindex, nofollow
              $observer->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setRobots('NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW');
          }
     }
}
```

Comment: where "your condition here" could be a custom attribute, this would allow you to mass import the custom attribute value quickly for 1000's of products.

Comment: @paj. Sure. It can be anything. A product attribute, a config setting.